# d3 graph size not updating

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a live-updating grouped bar graph which I modified from [this example](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920026938/chapter_09/17_randomized_data.html). I want the graph to reflect the size of my data array as the array size changes, but in my current code, the d3 graph stays stuck at the initial length of the data array and doesn't grow along with the array, which will be limited when it reaches a certain length.

Why am I able to update the values for bars in the graph, but not change number of bars as the dataset changes in size?

My code is below, and in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jme9t3h4/).

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div id="disp"></div> 
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var main = function () {
        console.log(dataset.toString())
        var a  = { a: 'temp', b: 50+Math.floor(Math.random() * 30)}
        var b = { a: 'hum', b: 20+Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)}

        // add new elements
        dataset.push(a);    
        dataset.push(b);

       // limit to 8 elements
        if(dataset.length > 8){ 
        dataset.shift(); 
        dataset.shift();
        }
        //update graph
        update(dataset); 

    }

      // dataset below will show 6 bars animating
     // var dataset = [{ a: 'temp', b: 5},{ a: 'hum', b: 8},{ a: 'temp', b: 4},
     // { a: 'hum', b: 9},{ a: 'temp', b: 15},{ a: 'hum', b: 12}];

    var dataset = [{ a: 'temp', b: 5},{ a: 'hum', b: 8}];


    var w = 600;
    var h = 250;

    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.1);

    var rectw = 20;
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, 80])
            .range([0, h]);

    var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

    var bars = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset);

    barsenter = bars.enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'bars');


    barsenter
       .append("rect")
           .attr('class', 'temp')
       .filter(function(d){ return d.a == 'temp'})
       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return (rectw+2)*i*2;
       })
       .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d.b);
       })
       .attr("width", rectw)
       .attr("height", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.b);
       })
       .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(" + (d.b * 4) +",0, 0)";
       });

    barsenter
       .append("rect")
           .attr('class', 'hum')
       .filter(function(d){ return d.a == 'hum'})
       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return rectw+2+(rectw+2)*i*2;
       })
       .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d.b);
       })
       .attr("width", rectw)
       .attr("height", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.b);
       })
       .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return  "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.b * 5) + ")";
       });


    // update function
    var update = function(dataset) {  

    bars.select(".temp")
       .data(dataset)
           .filter(function(d){ return d.a == 'temp'})
       .transition()
       .delay(function(d, i) {
           return i / dataset.length * 1000;
       })
       .duration(500)
       .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d.b);
       })
       .attr("height", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.b);
       })
       .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(" + (d.b * 4) +",0, 0)";
       });

    bars.select(".hum")
       .data(dataset)
           .filter(function(d){ return d.a == 'hum'})
       .transition()
       .delay(function(d, i) {
           return i / dataset.length * 1000;
       })
       .duration(500)
       .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d.b);
       })
       .attr("height", function(d) {
            return yScale(d.b);
       })
       .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return  "rgb(0, 0, " + (d.b * 5) + ")";
       });

    }


    main();
    window.setInterval(function(){ main() }, 1000);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [these](http://animateddata.co.uk/lab/d3enterexit/) [two](https://medium.com/@c_behrens/enter-update-exit-6cafc6014c36#.qei94qhqk) descriptions, It seemed that understanding d3's enter() and exit() functions is the key.

I made this snippet to demonstrate a bar graph with an update function.

```js
//main code
// init data
var dataset = [];
function fillArray(arr){
 arr.push({'value' : Math.floor(Math.random()*50)});
}
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
fillArray(dataset);
}

// add 
var btnfunc = function(){
fillArray(dataset);
 //update graph
 update();
}

// remove 
var btnfunc2 = function(){
 dataset.pop()
//update graph
 update();
}

// randomize
var btnfunc3 = function(){
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) { 
dataset[i].value = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
}
//update graph 
update();
}


//d3 code
//init graph
var width = 700, height = 120;

var canvas = d3.select('#disp')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 10]) 
        .range([0, 700]);

var h = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 110])
        .range([0, height]); 

var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 80])
        .range([200, 0]);
//create selection
var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect");

//update function
function update(){
//update selection
bars = canvas.selectAll("rect").data(dataset);
//append new bars      
bars.enter().append("rect");
//bar attributes
bars
  .attr('width', 20)  
  .attr('height', function(d){ return h(d.value); }) 
  .attr('y', function(d){ return height - h(d.value); } )
  .attr('x', function (d, i) { return i*14*2; })
  .style('fill', 'red');
//remove bars
bars.exit().remove();

}

//1st display
update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="disp"></div> 
<button onclick="btnfunc()">add</button>
<button onclick="btnfunc2()">remove</button>
<button onclick="btnfunc3()">random</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To the question:
*not change number of bars as the dataset changes in size?*

Reason you are creating the rects only once when the dataset had only two values.

```
barsenter
       .append("rect")
```

In the update section you are not creating but just updating the rectangles with the value.

So the fix is that in the update section do the append as well.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work so far, could you elaborate on what should be changed in the update function?.